# How can I force update all the snapshot Gradle dependencies in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I have a project with SNAPSHOT dependencies using gradle as its build tool in intellij.

The problem is that intellij is using SNAPSHOTS that are now outdated.
[image]

When I build the project on the command line

```
gradle build or 
gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

On command line the latest dependencies are fetched. I also setup my grade file to always download snapshot dependencies [according to this answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-gradle-to-download-newer-snapshots-to-gradle-cache-when-using-an-ivy-repository/7344).

How can I force intellij to download all dependencies?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have run into some very sticky snapshots. There are a few options you can try:

- On the Gradle tab (right side of UI), click the blue circling arrows icon, which should refresh the dependencies (works in most cases)
- If that does not work, try running the gradle command *in* IntelliJ using the Green "run Gradle command" icon - this runs the command in IntelliJs environment not that of your local machine.
- If both of those fail, you can modify your Gradle resolutionStrategy settings to something like:

  `configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 4, 'hours'
      resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 4, 'hours'
  }`

  This config change is a last-ditch option and should be used sparingly. It basically tells Gradle to refresh the local cache more often. You should click the IntelliJ Gradle refresh button after making these changes.

Comment: On the Gradle tab in Intellij there is a green icon along the top that will allow you to execute a gradle command in the IDE.

Comment: Ah, I got what you meant, and then? `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies`?

Answer (score 144):

In IntelliJ 2017.2 you can right-click on the project name in the
Gradle Tool Window and select **Refresh dependencies** from the context menu.

[image: Refresh Gradle dependencies in IntelliJ 2017.2]

This will refresh all your dependencies, not only the SNAPSHOTS, so it might take a while. I don't know if other versions of IntelliJ also have this feature.

Comment: This works but it is very slow.  Does anyone know how to optimize to only get the latest SNAPSHOTS?

Comment: If you are uploading the snapshots then appending the commit number if a quick fix... 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-1

Comment: This dont work if the snapshot have changes and have the same version.

Answer (score 34):

Another option is to open up the Project Structure, and under Project Settings, Libraries, find the dependency in the list and remove it. Then press the Gradle refresh blue circling arrows icon and IntelliJ should fetch the latest version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, after trying the other answers (maybe it needs to be done after the --refresh-dependencies solution).

Answer (score 24):

**IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2020.1**

Right-click on the project name in the Gradle Tool Window and select **Refresh Gradle Dependencies** from the context menu.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

#### EDIT

On Gradle 6+, snapshots are `changing` by default. So, no need to set `changing = true` anymore. But you still need to set `resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor` to 0 seconds.

---

#### Previous answer:

Gradle caches changing modules for 24 hours by default. We can tell Gradle to refresh or redownload dependencies in the build script by marking those as 'changing'.

Follow these steps:

**Step #1**: Tell Gradle not to cache changing modules by set the value of the `cacheChangingModulesFor` property to 0 second:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

**Step #2**: Mark dependencies which are needed to be refreshed  or redownloaded, as changing module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.howtoprogram.buysell:payment-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT") {
        changing = true
    }
}
```

Source: [Refresh or Redownload Dependencies in Gradle](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/27/refresh-redownload-dependencies-gradle/)

Comment: the property is called isChanging on 6.8.x in kts dialiect. But seems to be a thing. Would be nice if they did that automatically for snapshot builds.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp Well, that's the case since Gradle 6, see the edit.

Comment: Yes, the caveat is that it only checks every 24 hours unless you change that to something more reasonable. We ended up configuring a `configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}` to work around that.

Comment: This is the best solution as to me.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to ensure that IntelliJ adds all dependencies is to invalidate the project caches and restart. It will take about a minute to reload the project.

INTELLIJ IDE

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
```

Now as for ensuring that the latest snapshot is used, you must specify the version of the dependency you are using in your gradle.build file.

Typically there is no 'latest' anchor version in most repositories. You'll simply have to look and see what the latest version is.

Theoretically if you knew the release dates and versioning system you could write a Groovy function that returned the dependency URL and pass it to implementation.

```
def getLatestVersion(){
 ...build version string
return version //As string
}

implementation getLatestVersion()
```

But it would not be recommended even if you referencing a CI/CD pipeline in case there were any changes outside of your control

Comment: Many thanks. Struggle on this several hours.