# Gradle download sources failed

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using Gradle build tool and I can't get the source code and docs for spark-core.
I've already searched and applied:

```
idea {
    project {
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work for me. I suppose I'm missing something like rebuild the whole project or download just these pieces.

I applied `./gradlew cleanIdea idea` as well.

When I try to click with pressed command on SparkConf.class I press `Download Sources` I get `Sources not found for: org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.5`

And the result from the run tab:

```
21:11:29: Executing task 'DownloadSources'...

:DownloadSources FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.124 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/06/97bzw1l51r59l65thfzs7hd80000gn/T/ijmiscinit1.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':downloadSourcesFrom_MavenRepo_91653a2f-0439-4794-b77a-3812f9926728'.
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
21:11:29: Task execution finished 'DownloadSources'.
```

Here is 2 pretty long task outputs:

- DownloadSources --info: https://pastebin.com/D07JmGXT
- DownloadSources --stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/6ceKhwrk

Idea.log https://pastebin.com/EQcDxPwb

Latest public Intellij build: 2020.1.1 installed via Toolbox
Latest MacOS: 10.15.4
Java 1.8 jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg, downloaded from oracle.com

Could you please help me to realize what should I do to fix it?

Comment: did you try adding the sources classifier in the build.gradle?

Comment: `compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.3',classifier:'sources'` this works fine for me

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy thank you for the thought. Should I run build after this or should it work instantly?

Comment: you should import the changes and then it should work

Comment: After I add this I did `invalidate and restart` from File and `clean rebuild` gradle task, but still can't reach the docs

Comment: invalidate doesnt help you, you need to refresh the gradle project so it can refresh the depedencies

Comment: in the gradle tool window, you should have a "reimport all projects" icon (like a circle)

Comment: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2020.1/gradle_tool_window_enabled.png The first one

Comment: I did `Refresh Gradle Dependencies` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47557700/5151861 still can't reach the docs and get failed while trying to download it

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy `reimport project` tried as well, still nothing :(

Comment: in the external libraries, do you see `spark-core_2.12-2.4.5-sources.jar` ?

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy from what I see I don't have it: https://imgur.com/a/T2pQ8x7

Comment: this is why you dont see the sources, if after you did a reimport it didnt change then something is wrong with your intellij/gradle setup. I would look into this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html

Comment: I tried to make this happen in the new project: `./gradlew build --warning-mode=all`
> Configure project :
The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation configuration instead.
        at build_ch9eewobhc2rtmdi9qkyp7xzn$_run_closure3.doCall(/Users/iamtodor/data_engineer/code/test_gradle/build.gradle:22)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

Comment: And still, no docs are available

Comment: Maybe you are running from behind corporate proxy and idea does not have it set up?

Comment: @charlie_pl nope, I do not have any proxy or VPN. I can reach https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ from my browser

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy the problem lays in Scala plugin, I had no installed Scala plugin before.

Comment: @charlie_pl the problem lays in Scala plugin, I had no installed Scala plugin before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem belongs to Scala plugin.
If you face this issue, it doesn't matter on build tool you are using Maven or Gradle probably installation of the Scala plugin solves your problem.

My Intellij report: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2686145

Well-known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127193